# Xcode Outlet/Action connection UITextField

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to add my text field as an **Outlet** in my ViewController.swift, but when I drag the text field from the Main.storyboard to the ViewController it only shows as **action** and I cannot change it to **Outlet**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too! I fixed it by clicking on the top bar of my UIViewController (in the storyboard looking window), then selecting the Identity Inspector on the right and in the top where it says Custom Class in bold there is a field called Class which I set to the viewcontroller file I was trying to control-drag the UITextField to. Once the Class was set to the right name I was able to control-drag for an outlet. I hope this helps.